# BottomNavigation Bar

Tags: android, navigationbar, bottom-navigation-view

[image: добавить такой элемент]

Подскажите, как вставить в бар элемент к нему не относящийся

Comment: Есть вот такой вариант https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44342530/how-to-make-bottom-navigation-show-menu-items-with-icon-and-text-except-center-i